# Using Chunksize and Dask to process 8GB Redshift table in Pandas with Missingno

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift, dask, chunks

I have successfully connected Python to a redshift table with my Jupyter Notebook. 
I sampled **1 day** of data (176707 rows) and performed a function using [Missingno](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno) to assess how much data is missing and where. No problem there.

Here's the code so far (redacted for security)...

```
#IMPORT NECESSARY PACKAGES FOR REDSHIFT CONNECTION AND DATA VIZ
import psycopg2
from getpass import getpass
from pandas import read_sql
import seaborn as sns
import missingno as msno

#PASSWORD INPUT PROMPT
pwd = getpass('password')

#REDSHIFT CREDENTIALS 
config = { 'dbname': 'abcxyz', 
           'user':'abcxyz',
           'pwd':pwd,
           'host':'abcxyz.redshift.amazonaws.com',
           'port':'xxxx'
         }

#CONNECTION UDF USING REDSHIFT CREDS AS DEFINED ABOVE
def create_conn(*args,**kwargs):
    config = kwargs['config']
    try:
        con=psycopg2.connect(dbname=config['dbname'], host=config['host'], 
                              port=config['port'], user=config['user'], 
                              password=config['pwd'])
        return con
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)

#DEFINE CONNECTION 
con = create_conn(config=config)

#SQL TO RETRIEVE DATASET AND STORE IN DATAFRAME 
df = read_sql("select * from schema.table where date = '2020-06-07'", con=con)

# MISSINGNO VIZ
msno.bar(df, labels=True, figsize=(50, 20))
```

This produces the following, which is exactly what I want to see:

[image]

However, I need to perform this task on a subset of the entire table, not just one day.

I ran...

```
SELECT "table", size, tbl_rows FROM SVV_TABLE_INFO
```

...and I can see that the table is a **total size of 9GB** and **32.5M rows**, although the sample I need to assess the data completion of is **11M rows**

So far I have identified 2 options for retrieving a larger dataset than the ~18k rows from my initial attempt.

These are:

1) Using chunksize 
2) Using Dask

**Using Chunksize**

I replaced the necessary line of code with this:

```
#SQL TO RETRIEVE DATASET AND STORE IN DATAFRAME 
df = read_sql("select * from derived.page_views where column_name = 'something'", con=con, chunksize=100000)
```

This still took several hours to run on a MacBook Pro 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7 with 16 GB RAM and gave memory warnings toward the end of the task.
When it was complete I wasn't able to view the chunks anyway and the kernel disconnected, meaning the data held in memory was lost and I'd essentially wasted a morning.

**My question is:**

Assuming this is not an entirely foolish endeavour, would Dask be a better approach? If so, how could I perform this task using Dask?

The Dask documentation gives this example:

```
df = dd.read_sql_table('accounts', 'sqlite:///path/to/bank.db',
                  npartitions=10, index_col='id')  # doctest: +SKIP
```

But I don't understand how I could apply this to my scenario whereby I have connected to a redshift table in order to retrieve the data.

Any help gratefully recieved.